# Make edges between clusters avoid other clusters

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

I have a few clusters. Some of nodes inside those clusters are connected and dot puts the clusters in such order that some edges cross other clusters (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsmyR.png here you can see that edges between A and C cross cluster B). How can I avoid that and in the same time leave the setting: splines=false (or have different splines settings for outside of the cluster and inside of the cluster)?  Or maybe you can somehow force the position of the clusters (for example I would like to have my clusters ordered in the star schema).